# printing an array element with key

Tags: php, arrays, escaping

I have the following php code:

```
$special_term_id = 55;
$special_term_name = $form['shs_term_node_tid_depth']['#options']["'" .$special_term_id. "'"];

echo $special_term_name;
```

This does not work, while if I write as:

```
$special_term_id = 55;
$special_term_name = $form['shs_term_node_tid_depth']['#options']['55'];

echo $special_term_name;
```

Then it works, what could be the cause?

Comment: Is it a normal array (integer indexed) or an associative array (string indexed)?

55 is an integer
'55' is a string

Comment: `$special_term_name = $form['shs_term_node_tid_depth']['#options'][$special_term_id];`

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes you are spot on! that was the issue :-)

Answer (score 2):

The following 2 array statements accesses different keys from the same array:

```
$array["'" .$special_term_id. "'"];

$array['55'];
```

The first one is looking for a key `"'55'"` (the outer quotes delimit the string) and the second one is looking for `"55"` (the quotes delimit the string).

Since the array only has a value for the second key, the first statement cannot work.

If you want to convert the int to string use `(string)$special_term_id`

Comment: There's no need to convert the int to a string, PHP treats them the same as array indexes.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, it was quotes causing this problem. This solved it:

    $special_term_name = $form['shs_term_node_tid_depth']['#options'][$special_term_id];